# Authenticate websocket clients using tokens?

Tags: authentication, websocket, token

I want to provide a websocket based Service to my registered users. 
The Website Frontend is running on Server A, the WebSocket-Service is running on Server B.

I want to make sure that Server B won't grant acces to an user that is not authenticated by Server A. Also I want to avoid that a session can be hijacked.

I came up with this approach but I never implemented security for websockets.
Might this be a good approach?:

- When a client wants to connect with my WebSocket, Server A requests a
  token from Server B. The Server B will generate this Token and send
  it back to Server A.
- Server B will store the token in a cache.
- Now the client is allowed to connect to the WebSocket. The clients
  first Message contains the token.
- Server B checks whether the token can be found in the cache and
  whether the token is already used by an active Session.
- If everything is fine the client will be registered and is allowed
  use the service.

Is this a good approach? Is there a better solution I wont have to implement by myself?

I read this solution:
[Best way to create a TOKEN system to authenticate web service calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432664/best-way-to-create-a-token-system-to-authenticate-web-service-calls)

But since my users will send up to 500 messages per minute (thats the highest possible value..but still possuble) I think this could cause some trouble...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebSockets authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701373/websockets-authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with cookies?

If both servers are in the same 2nd level domain (web.example.com and websocket.example.com), they can share cookies.

The websocket connection will send the existing cookies for that 2nd level domain during the negotiation.

So you can perform authentication in the web server, return an authentication cookie, and then the websocket will send that cookie to the server again. The websocket server should be able of opening and reading the cookie.

"500 messages per minute" are 8 messages per second, it should not be a problem. Websocket connections are established once, there is not a new connection per each message. A websocket is different than a webservice.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you think could I avoid CORS attacks? Should I send the session cookie with the first message or is there a way to send that information while the connection is established?

Comment: The cookie is sent on connection, as part of the handshake. You should use a secure token as cookie value, then the security model is the same than in a normal web app.

Comment: When my servers are on the same 2nd level domain, will the HttpSession ID be identical? In this case I wouldn't even need a cookie, right?

Comment: Probably the session id is already in a cookie. Check how your platform handles sessions, but probably there are already tools for session and authentication management.

Comment: Hi, I just followed your answer but I'm facing a problem. How can I send the cookie to the websocket server? I'd like to do this during the handshake but I there is no httpsession to read. Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565223/websocket-handshake-has-no-httpsession-no-sharing-of-session-between-war-mod please?

Comment: I have no idea about Wildfly. If you are actually returning a cookie, the WebSocket connection should send that cookie, it is basic HTTP mechanics, so probably the problem is something related with Wildfly.

Comment: maybe this happens because my cookie contains a path? Frontend: Domain: localhost, Path:Frontend; WS Path:Websocket

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755499/how-to-change-jsessionid-cookie-path-to-server-root-in-spring-app-on-jetty looks like I can't change the path to root

Comment: [Don't use cookies. Use tokens instead](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/)

Comment: Cookies are limiting when you want to build native apps or use CORS. See https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster-client/issues/9

Comment: There are additional CSRF issues with websockets since there is no SOP and you can't set headers. See here https://gist.github.com/kag0/f3c43b60b700af39563c050b29a3dfb2 for more on authenticating websockets with cookies.